# Write a function that may return either one or more values

Tags: c++, idioms

Suppose I want to write a function that, say, returns the sum of f(x) for x in a certain range.

```
double func() {
    double sum = 0.;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        sum += f(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

But sometimes, in addition to the final sum I also need the partial terms, so I can do

```
pair<vector<double>,double> func_terms() {
    double sum = 0.;
    vector<double> terms(100);
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        terms[i] = f(i);
        sum += terms[i];
    }
    return {terms, sum};
}
```

The thing is, this is code duplication. This seems very harmless in this example, but suppose the function is much larger (which it is in the situation that prompted me to ask this), and the two versions differ in just a handful of lines lines (in this example the logic is the same only the latter version stores the term in a vector before adding to sum, and returns a pair with that vector; any other logic is equivalent). Then I will have to write and maintain two nearly-identical versions of the same function, differing only in a couple lines and in the return statement. My question is if there is an idiom/pattern/best practice to deal with this kind of problem. Something that would let me share the common code between the two versions.

In short: I can write two functions and have to maintain two nearly-identical versions. Or I can just use the latter but that will be very wasteful whenever I just need the sum, which is unacceptable. What's the best pattern to deal with this?

---

I reckon that with C++17 one can do something like

```
template<bool partials>
double func(vector<double>* terms=nullptr) {
    double sum = 0.;
    if constexpr (partials)
        *terms = vector<double>(100);
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        if constexpr (partials) {
            (*terms)[i] = f(i);
            sum += (*terms)[i];
        } else {
            sum += f(i);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Which comes very close to what I intended, apart from using pointers (I can't use references because `terms` may be empty).

Comment: you can use `optional`, it is available in boost and afaik one of the latest c++ versions also has it

Comment: Get rid of `sum` and then `return {terms, std::accumulate(terms.begin(), terms.end(), 0.))}` ?

Comment: @Jarod42, that still requires two functions: one which returns {terms, std::accumulate...} and the other which returns {std::accumulate...} and doesn't address the question of code duplication when the code is more complicated than just a std:: accumulate call which is what the OP seems to be suggesting

Comment: Can you elaborate on the performance difference you observed in practice when you implemented `double func() { return func_terms().second; }`? The optimizer may in fact be better than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title says *"Write a function that may return either one or more values"*, but it's more than that; as your example shows, the function may also do a lot of different things long before a result is returned. There really is no general solution to such a broad problem.

However, for the specific case you've explained I'd like to offer a low-tech solution. You could simply implement both functions in terms of a third function and give that third function a parameter to determine whether the extra functionality is performed or not.

Here is a C++17 example, in which that third function is called `func_impl` and more or less hidden inside a namespace to make life easier for the client of `func` and `func_terms`:

```
namespace detail {
    enum class FuncOption {
        WithTerms,
        WithoutTerms
    };

    std::tuple<std::vector<double>, double> func_impl(FuncOption option) {
        auto const withTerms = option == FuncOption::WithTerms;
        double sum = 0.;
        std::vector<double> terms(withTerms ? 100 : 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            auto const result = f(i);
            if (withTerms) {
              terms[i] = result;
            }
            sum += result;
        }
        return std::make_tuple(terms, sum);
    }   
}

double func() {
    using namespace detail;
    return std::get<double>(func_impl(FuncOption::WithTerms));
}

std::tuple<std::vector<double>, double> func_terms() {
    using namespace detail;
    return func_impl(FuncOption::WithoutTerms);
}
```

Whether that's *too* low-tech is up to you and depends on your exact problem.

Comment: What I was thinking was almost something like this only that the compiler would actually generate the two versions of the function and statically dispatch to the appropriate function depending on the value of `option`. Because here there is *still* the creation and return of a vector and also a branch on every iteration (notwithstanding the fact that the compiler can host that out of the loop since `withTerms` is `const`), which means there is still a valid reason to just write the two separate versions.

Answer (score 1):

*Here was a solution that suggested to pass an optional pointer to vector and to fill it only if present. I deleted it as other answers mention it as well and as the latter solution looks much more elegant.*

You can abstract your calculation to iterators, so callers remain very simple and no code is copied:

```
auto make_transform_counting_iterator(int i) {
    return boost::make_transform_iterator(
            boost::make_counting_iterator(i),
            f);
}

auto my_begin() {
    return make_transform_counting_iterator(0);
}

auto my_end() {
    return make_transform_counting_iterator(100);
}

double only_sum() {
    return std::accumulate(my_begin(), my_end(), 0.0);
}

std::vector<double> fill_terms() {
    std::vector<double> result;
    std::copy(my_begin(), my_end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Nice suggestion, the second solution is much more elegant indeed. I removed the other one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way is to write a common function and use input parameter to do condition. Like this:

```
double logic(vector<double>* terms) {
    double sum = 0.;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        if (terms != NULL) {
            terms.push_back(i);
        }
        sum += terms[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

double func() {
    return logic(NULL);
}


pair<vector<double>,double> func_terms() {
    vector<double> terms;
    double sum = logic(&ret);
    return {terms, sum};
}
```

this method is used in many conditions. The Logic can be very complicated and with many input options. You can use the same logic through different parameters. 
But in most cases, We need not that much return values but just different input parameter.

Comment: That's very old-fashioned code; not only should `NULL` no longer be used ever since C++11 introduced `nullptr`, using a pointer is bad when we have `std::optional` since C++17 (and `boost::optional` or some self-made optional class before that). There's also a compilation error in your code when you access `terms` as if it was a reference and not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not for:

```
std::pair<std::vector<double>, double> func_terms() {
    std::vector<double> terms(100);

    for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i) {
        terms[i] = f(i);
    }
    return {terms, std::accumulate(terms.begin(), terms.end(), 0.)};
}
```

then maybe:

```
template <typename Accumulator>
Accumulator& func_helper(Accumulator& acc) {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        acc(f(i));
    }
    return acc;
}

double func()
{
    double sum = 0;
    func_helper([&sum](double d) { sum += d; });
    return sum;    
}

std::pair<std::vector<double>, double> func_terms() {
    double sum = 0.;
    std::vector<double> terms;

    func_helper([&](double d) {
        sum += d;
        terms.push_back(d);
    });

    return {terms, sum};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out an OOP solution, where a base class always compute sum and makes the current term available to derived classes, this way:

```
class Func
{
public:
    Func() { sum = 0.; }
    void func()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            double term = f(i);
            sum += term;
            useCurrentTerm(term);
        }
    }
    double getSum() const { return sum; }

protected:
    virtual void useCurrentTerm(double) {} //do nothing

private:
    double f(double d){ return d * 42;}
    double sum;
};
```

So a derived class can implement the virtual method and espose extra properties (other than sum):

```
class FuncWithTerms : public Func
{
public:
  FuncWithTerms() { terms.reserve(100); }
  std::vector<double> getTerms() const { return terms; }

protected:
  void useCurrentTerm(double t) { terms.push_back(t); }

private:
  std::vector<double> terms;
};
```

If one doesn't want to expose these classes, could fall back to functions and use them as a façade (yet **two** functions, but very manageable, now):

```
double sum_only_func()
{
  Func f;
  f.func();
  return f.getSum();
}

std::pair<std::vector<double>, double> with_terms_func()
{
  FuncWithTerms fwt;
  fwt.func();
  return { fwt.getTerms(), fwt.getSum() };
}
```

Comment: The idea is not too bad and the solution looks a bit cleaner than my own, but some details about the code are strange: no initialisation list in the constructor, no `const` for `getSum`, redundant `protected` where `private` would suffice, no `std::` in code that's probably in a header file.

Comment: I think you're right about const and std, thanks, I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this situation I think would be something like this:

```
double f(int x) { return x * x; }

auto terms(int count) {
    auto res = vector<double>{};
    generate_n(back_inserter(res), count, [i=0]() mutable {return f(i++);});
    return res;
}

auto func_terms(int count) {
    const auto ts = terms(count);
    return make_pair(ts, accumulate(begin(ts), end(ts), 0.0));
}

auto func(int count) {
    return func_terms(count).second;
}
```

[Live version](https://ideone.com/Vt3jvX).

But this approach gives `func()` different performance characteristics to your original version. There are ways around this with the current STL but this highlights an area where the STL is not ideal for composability. The [Ranges v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) library offers a better approach to composing algorithms for this type of problem and is in the process of standardization for a future version of C++.

In general there is often a tradeoff between composability / reuse and optimal performance. At its best C++ lets us have our cake and eat it too but this is an example where there is work underway to give standard C++ better approaches to handle this sort of situation.